# Get the textbox value and set in table

Tags: javascript

Someone please help me to pass the value of textbox and set it in the table using javascript? I am just a beginner and sorry for this question :(

```
Enter name: <input type="text" name="name">

<button type="button"> Add to table</button>

<table id="mytable">
 <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```js
var field = document.getElementById("value");
var button = document.querySelector('button');

if (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', addValue, false);
}

function addValue() {
  if (field.value !== '') {
    var table = document.querySelector('#content');

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    td.innerText = field.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    field.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
Enter name:
<input type="text" name="name" id='value'>

<button type="button">Add to table</button>

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='content'>
  </tbody>
</table>
```